# Dynamically update usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In my C# winform project I used several user controls.
Here it contain two option like this

```
Home > Person > Addperson

Home > Teacher > AddTeacher
```

Person and Teacher contain a listbox which display all person/teachers from database.
when I add person using **Addperson**, data entered successfully. But when I go back to **Person** It doesn't show anything. At the same time If I go back to home and enter into **AddTeacher** option, here from dropdown list I can find that newly added data.

Now if I add that person as a teacher and go back to **Teacher** it won't show anything but data actually inserted successfully. Then if I close the whole program and reopen than everything show correctly.

All I want is to refresh those *usercontrol* somehow so that every time any change happens it will show that change instantly without closing down whole program.

I tried different methods but none of them works. I tried refresh method. Also tried
with `datasource=null` before actual datasource declaration.

**Code for person Listbox:**

```
var personListDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

SqlCommand prsonListCmd = new SqlCommand("SQL QUERY", Connection);
SqlDataReader dr = prsonListCmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      ...
      personListDictionary.Add(Key, Value);
   }
}

PersonList.DisplayMember = "Value";
PersonList.ValueMember = "Key";        
PersonList.DataSource = new BindingSource(personListDictionary, null);
```

Comment: Well you have to somehow notify the Person or Teacher user controls that they have to refresh. One way is to raise OnEntityAdded or something similar in the AddPerson and AddTeacher user controls and handle it in Person or Teacher.

Comment: @sventevit I am not sure what you want to say. Please explain more. Is there any specific method to do such kind of refresh?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly, then you have one Windows form, which contains Person and AddPerson user controls. One option to solve this is to:

1. Add an OnPersonAdded event in the AddPerson user control:
2. Add a Refresh method in Person user control (the same code that you posted in your example)
3. Add a handler for OnPersonAdded in the main Windows form, which refreshes the data in the Person user control.

AddPerson user control:

```
public event EventHandler<object, EventArgs> OnPersonAdded;

// When you add a Person, then raise the event:
var handler = OnPersonAdded;
if (handler != null)
{
    OnPersonAdded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Person user control:

```
public void Refresh()
{
    // your code from the example
}
```

Parent windows form:

```
addPersonUserControl.OnPersonAdded += (sender, e) => personUserControl.Refresh();
```